# Relative homology of Klein bottle times two circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, klein-bottle

Using Künneth formula I calculated $H_n(K\times S^1) = 
\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \mathbb{Z} & n= 0 \\
      \mathbb{Z}^2\bigoplus  \mathbb{Z}_2& n=1 \\
      \mathbb{Z}\bigoplus  \mathbb{Z}_2& n=2\\
0&n\geq3
    \end{array}
\end{array}$

Now let $p,q\in K$ be different points in $K$. I have to calculate relative homology groups
$H_n(K\times S^1,\{p,q\}\times S^1).$

It is easy to verify that $H_n(\{p,q\}\times S^1)=
\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \mathbb{Z}^2 & n= 0 \\
      \mathbb{Z}^2&n=1\\
0&n\geq2
    \end{array}
\end{array}$

I'm stuck at relative long exact sequence:
$$\cdots\to 0 \to \mathbb{Z}^2\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrowtail H_2(K\times S^1,\{p,q\}\times S^1) \to \mathbb{Z}^2 \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\to H_1(K\times S^1,\{p,q\}\times S^1)\to\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\to0$$

I labelled some injections and surjections, but don't know how to continue. Is there a chance to use relative Mayer-Vietoris?
Thanks in advance.